# How can I write a query to show details of customers with duplicate names?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been looking around for quite a bit and cannot seem to find a solution that fits what I need.

I have a table with many, many customers and the issue is that there are many, many duplicates in this table.

I have been able to show the customers that have duplicate records and the count of how many are in the table with that same name, but now I am trying to split this up and show all of their information so we can confirm that the customer is the correct one when we look them up.

I was using this code:

```
SELECT COUNT(NAME), NAME
  FROM DEV.ALL_CUSTOMER
  GROUP BY NAME
  HAVING COUNT(NAME) > 1;
```

Which gives results that show like this:

```
COUNT(NAME) |       NAME
------------|-------------------
     3      | Smith, John
     2      | Doe, Jane
     2      | Doe, Joe
     2      | Smith, Jane
```

I then added in all of the informational fields I needed:

```
SELECT COUNT(NAME), NAME, TOTAL_PURCHASED, ADDRESS, CITY, STATE_PROV, POSTAL_CODE, COUNTRY, HOME_PHONE, WORK_PHONE, WORK_EXT, OTHER_PHONE, EMAIL_ADDRESS
  FROM DEV.ALL_CUSTOMER
  GROUP BY NAME, TOTAL_PURCHASED, ADDRESS, CITY, STATE_PROV, POSTAL_CODE, COUNTRY, HOME_PHONE, WORK_PHONE, WORK_EXT, OTHER_PHONE, EMAIL_ADDRESS
  HAVING COUNT(NAME) > 1;
```

But this still has them grouped and does not show the information for each record:

```
COUNT(NAME) |    NAME     | TOTAL_PURCHASED | ADDRESS |  CITY ...
------------|-------------|-----------------|---------|------- ..
     3      | Smith, John |        0        | (null)  | (null) ..
     2      | Doe, Jane   |        0        | (null)  | (null) ..
     2      | Doe, Joe    |        0        | (null)  | (null) ..
```

But I know for a fact that one of the five "John Smith" customers have purchased stuff.

Instead, I would like the results to come out like this:

```
NAME        | TOTAL_PURCHASED | ADDRESS       |  CITY ...
------------|-----------------|---------------|------- ..
Smith, John |       250       | 123 Fake St.  | (null) ..
Smith, John |        0        | (null)        | Oshawa ..
Smith, John |       300       | (null)        | Toronto .
Doe, Jane   |        0        | (null)        | (null) ..
Doe, Jane   |       300       | 456 Fake St.  | Toronto .
Doe, Joe    |      11235      | (null)        | (null) ..
Doe, Joe    |        0        | (null)        | (null) ..
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but isn't your desired results just "select * from all_customers order by name"?  Maybe with a `where name in (<<your group by/ having>>)`.

Comment: I have tried `SELECT [FIELDS] FROM DEV.ALL_CUSTOMER HAVING COUNT(NAME) > 1;` but it errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT c.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME) as cnt
      FROM DEV.ALL_CUSTOMER c
     ) c
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY NAME;
```

This will give you the rows that are duplicated on `NAME`.

Comment: I need only those fields I posted in the second `SELECT` statement. Do I just replace `c.*` in both selects in your code with those specific fields? Like so: `SELECT [SPECIFIC FIELDS] FROM (SELECT [SPECIFIC FIELDS], COUNT(NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME) as cnt FROM DEV.ALL_CUSTOMER c ) c WHERE cnt > 1 ORDER BY NAME;`

Comment: @WolfieeifloW . . . You can just put the fields you need in the outer `select`.